# ASP.NET Code won't evaluate in aspx file

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx file like

```
<div style="<%= MyFunc() %>"></div>
```

but when I view it in the webpage, it gives the style string the literal as seen above, not the evaluated MyFunc. What could cause this?

EDIT:

it turns out, the tag had runat="server" on it... removing that fixed the issue. Why would that be?

Comment: the syntax does not work for attributes of server controls - I guess the main reason is that the syntax is used for substitution and it takes place late (at rendering time) in page life cycle. For server controls, it would not work because attributes are control properties needs parsing before page init.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine, are you defining a function like this?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string MyFunc()
    {
        return "background-color:Red";
    }
```

Comment: precisely like that. It just isn't getting executed for me (but other code blocks are being executed that are inside of repeater controls). This code block is outside any asp.net control.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes.  ASP.NET outputs attribute values in double quotes literally.  Single quotes will allow the script to be executed.

```
<div style='<%= MyFunc() %>'></div>
```